# link to a domain removed from email

Tags: dns, firewall

We are send email to our users which contain a link to a page on one of our domains. For some of the users, the emails are quarantined by their company firewall/email exchange. Is there a central authority or repository where we can get our domain kind of whitelisted or prove that its genuine so that the emails are not quarantined?

Answer (score 0):

Short: No.
Longer: Wrong place to ask. You get negative votes because [email tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/email) says:

> Use this tag for questions involving code to send or receive email
> messages. Posting to ask why the emails you send are marked as spam is
> off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions about configuration of mail
> servers belong on Server Fault.

Comment: Removed email tag. Thanks.